# how to change magento 2 date.js form file

Tags: magento2, ui-form, datepicker, datetime

I want to change :

> magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/date.js file

and
set my custom date file , for this purpose I've added this line to my requirejs-config in my module :

```
'map': {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/date_form'
    }
},
```

but when I refresh page I get this error in console :

> Uncaught TypeError: elem.initContainer is not a function
>       at UiClass.initElement (collection.js:57)

and magento can't load date input element .

I think the problem is this part at date.js :

```
elementTmpl: 'ui/form/element/date',
```

it seems magento can't find this path for load it's html template .

I changed template path to this :

```
elementTmpl: 'Magento_Ui/form/element/date',
```

but noting changed .

how can I change this path base on my module ?

note : I don't want change date.html template file and I want to use magento default template file .

Comment: better put it on the same path like this `'map': {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/form/element/date'
    }
},`

Comment: @magefms thank you for reply , I did'nt get what you mean , elementTmpl path is in 
my custom date.js file magento can't find this path for load html template file. I think because this file is in my module , magento can't resolve this path .

Comment: yeah, you are right. what I mean is, instead of putting your custom date.js somewhere in your custom module put it in the same level with the core date.js in your custom module. check my first comment

Comment: @magefms , you were right, my problem was solved . thanks alot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to put your custom `date.js` on the same path level of core `date.js` like this

```
'map': { 
    '*': { 

        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/date' : 'MyNamespace_MyModule/js/form/element/date' 
      }
 },
```